# Determining the file system type of a file, using BSD functions

Tags: macos, mount, fstab

I like to get the properties for a specific file path's volume properties as shown by the `mount` command, without using that command and instead calling the POSIX or related APIs.

When using the `mount` command on OS X, I get a listing of all available volumes. `man mount` points me to `getfsent`, which returns a `struct fstab` structure with the data I am interested in.

When I invoke `getfsent()` the first time, I get the information about the root fs, i.e. for "/".

Problem is that I cannot get further mount points that way. `man getfsent` suggests that I should simply repeatedly call it to learn of further mount points, but the next call returns NULL. I suspec that this function only returns what the actual "/etc/fstab" file contains, not the other volumes that OS X dynamically mounts later on.

But since the `mount` command can list those additional vols, there must be a way. What is it? Alternatively, I might just look at the source code, but I cannot figure out in which of the many downloads available from opensource.apple.com it is included.

*Update:* For a solution to list all mounted volumes, see [How to iterate all mounted file systems on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843238).

Comment: Maybe using `dtruss` with `mount` can help to identify the syscall you need.

Comment: A starting point is to download [FSMegaInfoGUI](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/code/). The software is old (based on some Apple source code) but is still working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that, for learning the properties, such as file system type, of a particular file's volume, I can also call `statfs()` and read out the `fstypename` field. That way, I don't have to iterate over the mounted file systems. I will edit the question accodingly now.